# Why does my SQL connection get stuck when I use DriverManager.getConnection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have Java code that looks as follows and a MySQL database running on my machine.

```
System.out.println("Loading JDBC");     
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();           
System.out.println("JDBC loaded");      
System.out.println("Establishing connection");
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:1186/dbname","username","password");
System.out.println("Connection established");
```

However, the output I get is the following:

```
Loading JDBC
JDBC loaded
Establishing connection
```

and then nothing? it doesn't report an error connecting, so it must be connected.
What's going on? why isn't it moving to the next line of code?

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: How long is it getting stuck ?

Comment: Put that statement into a try catch block and see what the exception is...

Comment: it is in a try/catch block, no exception, it just stops giving output but the program is still running

Comment: Are you manually able to connect to MySql using your "username" and "password" ??...

Comment: I tried
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 5000 -u username -password password
and got 

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

am I inputting the password correct? does it need any 's or "s? if it's right, how do I grant 'username' access?

Comment: Have you tried logging in using root ??

Comment: I managed to log in using 'username'
Furthermore, I get the same problem if I replace "username" with "root" and "password" with ""
what's going on?

Comment: If you were able to log in with "username"...try logging in from your program now...

Comment: nope, still not going. Furthermore, if I remove 'dbname' (i.e. just use "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:1186/"), it does the same. It's like it's establishing a connection, but does not get a response...

Comment: you've mentioned port 5000 while there is 1186 in your code.

Comment: that actually helped, now I'm getting a new error "om.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'dbname'". How do I grand 'username' access to dbname?

Answer (score 1):

Few points:

1. What is the name of database? If you are trying to run the code shown above, than database name must be "dbname", username must be "username" and password must be "password".
2. Is your MySQL listening to port 1186? I am just wondering as generally at the time of installation default port is set to 3306.

If you want to follow steps involved in connecting MySQL with JDBC, you can take a look to this tutorial for [JDBC Steps.](http://www.apekshit.com/t/51/Steps-to-connect-Database-using-JAVA)

Jwalant

Answer (score 0):

I usually do not put in a port number after the IP address. I use SQLYog which is an user interface for mysql. SQLYog is much easier to use than the  MySql command line.