# Why does my SQL connection get stuck when I use DriverManager.getConnection, without any error?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I need to connect to my database from a standalone Java application.

I try with this code, but it gets stuck on the `DriverManager.getConnection` line.

```
try{
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.11:1121/TEST"; 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
     System.out.println("Before");
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"test","test"); 
     System.out.println("After");
} catch (SQLException e  ) { 
     System.err.println("Sql exception! "); 
     System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

The output I get is the following:

```
Before
```

and nothing else.
This is the db configuration page in MySQL(obviously it works via MySQL) 
[image: property]

I'd appreciate any help

[Same old question's but without answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714449/why-does-my-sql-connection-get-stuck-when-i-use-drivermanager-getconnection)

Comment: So is the database your connecting to a MySQL database or an Oracle database?  If it's Oracle you will need to use the appropriate driver and have the appropriate connect string (have a look at https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/)

Comment: you're right Man.
Stupid error, it's an Oracle db.
Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to connect to an Oracle database with MySQL driver. According to your configuration, you should change the connection string from `jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.11:1121/TEST` to `jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.11:1121:1521:xe` and use the Oracle driver `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. You can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested from [Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren), the error was that is it an Oracle db.
I solved editing the code as follow

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.11:1511:XE"; 
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"test","test");
```